How to return a json containing a model object, as well as all the models related to it in Django
I have been working on a project in django, and I am stuck trying to extract some concepts, and parse their rules or complex rules depending on the concept's instance_type, and the rule clauses for each rule, and then put them in a json like format.
This is the model structure to give you a quick view of the database

and this is how its implementation in short:
class RuleClause(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default="")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=clauses_types_choices, default="StatsRuleClause")

class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default=DEFAULT_NAME)  # , unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    clauses = models.ManyToManyField(RuleClause, through="RuleClauseRule")

class ComplexRule(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default=DEFAULT_NAME, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rules = models.ManyToManyField(Rule, through="RuleComplexRule")

class Concept(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=DEFAULT_NAME, unique=True)
    instance_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    instance_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=concept_type_choices)


And this is the desired output:
{"concepts": [
   {
      "name": "Concept_1",
      "instance_type": "rule"
      "instance_id": {
           "name": "rule_1",
           "description": "",
           "clauses": [
            {
                "name": "Clause_1",
                "type": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Clause_2",
                "type": ""
            }]
       }
   },
   {
      "name": "Concept_2",
      "instance_type": "complex_rule"
      "instance_id": {
           "name": "complex_rule_1",
           "description": "",
           "rules": [
           {
                "name": "Rule_2",
                "description": "",
                "clauses": [
                {
                    "name": "clause_1",
                    "type": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "clause_4",
                    "type": ""
                }]
           }]
       }
   }
]}


Important: Keep in mind I am also considering query optimization here. Typically by avoiding the "n+1" problème
I have tried several methods, knowing that I should not change the models, I am struck in retrieving them. I have tried several methods but I get an error everytime because of how django deals with its build-in functions and classes.
For example, one of the errors I got while trying one of the failed approaches is this:
def get_instance(concept):

    instance = {}
    if concept['type'] == "rule":
        rule = Rule.objects.get(id=concept["instance_id"])
        clauses = rule.clauses.all()
        rule.clauses = clauses     #error in this line
        instance = rule
    elif concept['type'] =="rules_group":
        rule_group = ComplexRule.objects.filter(id=concept["instance_id"]).select_related('rules').all()
        instance = rule_group
    else:
        print(f"This is different I don't know this type: {concept.type} \n")
    return instance

It says while assiging the clauses to the rules.clauses.
"Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use clauses.set() instead."



Well you can prefetch_related(), see the code I dropped at code dump and try it.
